# How to create an instant app for Google Play Developement console, without using Android Studio?

Tags: android, javafx-8, gluon-mobile, android-instant-apps, google-play-console

I want to create an instant app apk for testing the integration of the billing API in the product, through Google Play.

I have not used Android Studio for creating the product. So, in this case, can I build an instant app apk without using Android Studio. And, can I debug this apk without Android Studio? By which way?

If it is not possible to generate and test an instant app apk without using Android Studio, how do you do with it?

My development configuration:

- Product made in JavaFX 8, with JavaFXports,Gluon with Eclipse
- Billing API for Google Play:

  ```
  gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.InAppBillingService  
  gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.inappbilling.Product
  ```

Note1:
The following article shows how to create this instant file, with Android Studio
  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#3

Note2:
About the tests "can I debug this apk without Android Studio? By which way? ", it seems that I understand how to do.
In Google console, I add a *secondary* account that is my tester account. It is defined with another email address.
Then, after creating the instant app (TBD), I publish it, the Google Play Development server warns my secondary account about that. Note that this app contains some System.out.println for debugging the billing code.
Then, on the tester side,I download the app from the server and I can now test it. By this way, it is now possible to finalize the debug of my product, especially about the billing, by catching the traces provided by my phone that had installed the app.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to build it with the [Gluon Plugin for Eclipse](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.0/#eclipse-plugin).
and there also is the [Buildship Plugin](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship); which even even seems to used - guess you'd merely need to provide the InstantApps SDK, with the SDK Manager and then configure the splits accordingly - and build with Buildship. so far the [gluon-samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples) don't feature an InstantApps example yet (because it is mere the question, if Gluon would also support this); maybe consider, if you even do require these splits, while probably not even having a prototype available (which means, there currently is nothing to split).

Comment: Martin,  
Indeed, I had already installed the Gluon plugin and its buildship. Otherwise, it was not possible to build any apk file for Android platform.

For beginning any test with Google Play Development console, it waits for an instant app release file,first. This file is a zip fille. Android Studio generates this zip file . But, without Android studio, I don't know how to do.  

More generaly, I think there are people that already used this solution JavaFX8 and Gluon for commercialising an Android product, through Google Play. So, how do they made the in-app billing tests?

Comment: here it shows the differences, which appear to be merely related to the packaging: https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/convert-to-instant-app ...and even without Android Studio, one can simply build with `./gradlew` (or `gradlew.bat`); the Gradle wrapper; with Jenkins one can also build and test head-less, with no GUI at all. also see https://medium.com/bleeding-edge/testing-in-app-purchases-on-android-a6de74f78878 for testing in-app billing.

Comment: Martin:my problem is that Google Play Console demands a zip file for rolling out an internal test. After searching more info, I found that Google waits for a base module (the zip file) including the apk file (installed module) AND the instant module. So, my more accurate question is: how to generate an instant module without Android Studio? Thanks in advance Note that the following procedure is under Android Studio and seems to be very heavy: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#3

Comment: zipping a few APK would be a simple Gradle task ...Android Studio uses nothing else but Gradle; while it's rather the opposite, due to much automation and suggestions. maybe read the previous comment again on "how to generate an instant module without Android Studio?" it is nothing else but `./gradlew build`.

Comment: Martin: indeed, the "gradlew build" allows to build an apk. I use it for a long time for my development. But, except if I don't understand what is the request in Google Play Development console - Release Management - Instant App Release - Edit Release?. , they require an instant app which specific features as mentioned in this article provided for people that use Android Studio:See: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#3 But, in my case I don't use Android Studio. So, how to generate an instant app as required by Google? –

Comment: Did you use the "com.android.feature" pluging as described in [this doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/create-base-feature-module)? If so, I would imagine gradle to build a different artifact than the APK.

Comment: I think I had not used the right way for easily testing an app through Google Play Console developer. In fact, there are two different sections in "Release management": "App releases" and "Android instant app". The second one is described in the previous URL of our discussion (codelabs). So, this approach (instant app) is inappropriate for beginning an app test with Google. "Internal test track" in  "App releases" is better. So, this discussion is closed, now. Perhaps, later, I'll come back to the instant apps ...